# PHP submit form to another page, and run the method

Tags: php, submit

I have 2 php file : a.php and b.php

i want to submit data from a.php to b.php. But i tried, not run in b.php. (i want to run "search" method in b.php after input in a.php).

Thanks

Here is my code

a.php

```
<form action="b.php" name="form1" method="post" >
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" >
<input type="submit" value=" "></form>
```

b.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
<input type="search" value="<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="cari" value=" "></form>
<?php $search = $_POST['search']; $cari = $_POST['cari']; if($cari){
if($search != "") { $query = "SELECT  * FROM kondef where poin
like'%$search%' or deskripsi like '%$search%'"; $result =   $db>
query($query);}  else { die (mysql_error()); }while($row = $result- 
fetchArray()) {?><tr>   <td><?php echo $row['poin'];?></td><td><?php echo 
$row['deskripsi'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['link'];?></td></tr><?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `curl` in `a.php` to send a POST request to `b.php`. There are many tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the code bellow

a.php

```
<form action="b.php" name="form1" method="post" >
   <input type="search" name="search" id="search" >
   <input type="submit" name="cari" value="submit">
</form>
```

b.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="search" value="<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>" name="search">
    <input type="submit" name="cari" value="submit">
</form> 
<table>

<?php $search = $_POST['search'];
    if(($search != "") && ($_POST['cari'] != "")) { 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM kondef WHERE poin like '%$search%' or deskripsi like '%$search%'";
        $result = $db->query($query);
    } else {
        die (mysql_error()); 
    };
    while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['poin'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['deskripsi'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['link'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @mateus, just missed name="cari" , in my submit button